# Next.js: Issue with Navigating Between Pages in a Nested Folder Structure

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I'm working on a Next.js application where I'm facing an issue while trying to navigate between pages in a nested folder structure. Here's my project's folder structure:

- app

  - (site)

    - components

      - auth

        - LoginForm.js
        - SignupForm.js
    - page.js
  - pages

    - LoginPage.tsx
    - SignupPage.tsx

In the SignupForm component located in components/auth, I'm using the Link component to navigate to the LoginPage. However, I keep encountering a "page not found" error. Here's the relevant code snippet from SignupForm.js:

> ```
> import Link from 'next/link';
>
> const SignupForm = () => {
> return (
>     <div>
> Your signup form JSX */}
>
> Link to navigate to the login page */}
>       <p>Already have an account? <Link href="/loginpage">Login</Link></p>
>     </div>
>   );
> };
>
> export default SignupForm;
> ```

I expected that when I click on the "Login" link within the SignupForm, it would navigate me to the LoginPage without encountering a "page not found" error. I'm seeking assistance in identifying any mistakes in my setup or any missing steps that might be causing this issue. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe NextJS routes are case sensitive, so you may need to rename your file loginpage.tsx to match the Link href.